# How to force a git revert

Tags: git

My git log looks like this:

```
commit b265eb43abd7704ed2560cca7c635dbd47b677b0
Date:   Sun Feb 25 10:20:58 2018 -0500

    added C3

commit 536d071bf99059ff8b519ae96ce6e97d92fbc7d7
Date:   Sat Feb 24 20:50:15 2018 -0500

    added B2

commit 6e46e4ff4135b4df55866a5df9af963e3d6ff218
Date:   Sat Feb 24 11:07:58 2018 -0500

    added a

commit 93ad202a08660a62f76496d728a3a89d727350a9
Date:   Sat Feb 24 11:05:56 2018 -0500

    first commit
```

I want to undo my previous commits and go back to commit 6e46e4ff4135b4df55866a5df9af963e3d6ff218. However, I want to preserve the history and do not want to remove "added C3" and "added B2" from the git log, so that rules out git reset --hard 6e46e4ff4135b4df55866a5df9af963e3d6ff218.

I did some reading online and people say that the perfect tool for this is "git revert". I try "git revert 6e46e4ff4135b4df55866a5df9af963e3d6ff218" and see the following

```
error: could not revert 6e46e4f... added a
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

I opened up the file I am trying to revert and saw the following:

```
Test
<<<<<<< HEAD

adding A
adding B
adding C
=======
>>>>>>> parent of 6e46e4f... added a
```

Someone told me this means I have a "merge conflict". But I do not want to MERGE the current state of the project with the old state of the project - I want to REPLACE the current state of the project with the old state of the project.

Is there any way to simply replace the current state of the project with an old commit, and have that be the new commit? I could do this manually by doing 1) git checkout , 2) copying the checked out project to a backup directory, 3) doing git checkout master in the main folder, 3) deleting all the files in the main folder replacing them with the backup of the old commit. But I would prefer to learn how to do it the git way. I would also prefer to avoid a branching solution, because I want to learn to use "git revert" - if it can't be used in this very basic, straightforward, canonical example, what could it possibly be used for?

Comment: Why don't you remove the conflict, commit and then revert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

revert undoes a commit; it does not go back to a certain point.

if you still have a clean tree are at `b265eb4`, just go like this:
(I mean you might want to `git reset --hard b265eb4` before you start to get back to where you were before you tried the revert)

```
git revert b265eb4
git revert 536d071
```

then check that it worked like this

```
git diff 6e46e4f
```

your should have the same files as in that commit, but have the mistakes, and then reverts in the history

.... or if you want to undo the two bad commits in a single commit ...

```
git reset --hard 6e46e4f # to make the files how you want them
git reset b265eb4 # to get back to the last commit
git diff # should see local changes that undo everything in the last two commits
git add -A
git commit -m"undo last couple commits"
git diff 6e46e4f # the state of the files should be the commit you wanted to go back to
```

Answer (score 13):

Git Revert Commit:
Undo 1 commit:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

OR

```
$ git reset --hard COMMIT
```

Remove last commit:

```
$ git push -f
```

This will destroy any local modifications.
Don't do it if you have uncommitted work you want to keep.

```
$ git reset --hard COMMIT
```

Comment: git reset --hard is enough for the answear

Answer (score 1):

Beside two

```
git revert b265eb43abd7704ed2560cca7c635dbd47b677b0
git revert 536d071bf99059ff8b519ae96ce6e97d92fbc7d7
```

you can checkout the target position and commit it

```
git checkout 6e46e4ff4135b4df55866a5df9af963e3d6ff218 -- .
git commit -m 'reverted some stuff'
```